# How to obtain Firebase Installation ID to test Firebase In-App Messaging in iOS 13+?

Tags: ios, firebase, ios13, firebase-analytics, firebase-in-app-messaging

I'm trying to implement Firebase In-App Messaging SDK within my iOS Project.
I already added by project in Firebase console and created a new Campaign. I want to test if the campaign is being triggered from Firebase Console to my iOS App but when I try to publish it, I'm being told to enter my Firebase Installation ID. I followed the steps from Firebase In-App Messaging documentation wherein I should addd this argument "-FIRDebugEnabled" in schemes. But when I run the App, I'm getting this error in Xcode logs ->[Firebase/InAppMessaging][I-IAM280002] Firebase In App Messaging was not configured with FirebaseAnalytics.

Is there another way to obtain the Firebase Installation ID? 
I'm using Xcode 12, Swift 5.

Answer (score 1):

Include `pod 'Firebase/Analytics'` in the Podfile to build Firebase Analytics into the app.

Comment: Hi, it's included already. I'm getting the mentioned error even if the Firebase Analytics pod is included.

Comment: Something about the configuration is likely off.  You could debug why https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/FirebaseInAppMessaging/Sources/Analytics/FIRIAMAnalyticsEventLoggerImpl.m#L72 is being hit or post a reproducible example in an issue at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues

Answer (score 1):

In app messaging for IOS

Step 1:
[Add the Firebase In-App Messaging SDK to your project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/get-started?platform=ios#add_the_sdk_to_your_project)

Step 2:
[Add the Firebase installations SDK to your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/manage-installations#add_the_sdk_to_your_app)

Step 3:
[Get firebase installation ID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/manage-installations#retrieve_client_identifiers)

Step 4:
[Xcode configuration to get firebase installation ID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/get-started?platform=ios#send_a_test_message_2)

Step 5:
Go to firebase console -> messaging -> new campaign -> in-app messaging -> fill style and content -> hit Test on device button -> add Firebase installation id -> hit test button

Re-run the app again to see in app message

Answer (score -1):

Get your app's installation ID [Documentation Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/in-app-messaging/get-started?authuser=1&platform=ios#get_your_apps)

To conserve power, Firebase In-App Messaging only retrieves messages from the server once per day. That can make testing difficult, so the Firebase console allows you to specify a test device that displays messages on demand.

That testing device is determined by a Firebase installation ID provided by the Firebase installations service. To find your testing app's installation ID, run the app with the runtime command argument -FIRDebugEnabled:

1. With your Xcode project open, select Product > Scheme > Edit scheme... from the top menu bar.
2. Open the Arguments tab of the dialog that pops up.
3. Click + Add items under Arguments Passed On Launch.
4. Enter "-FIRDebugEnabled" in the newly-created field.
5. Click Close, then run your app.

Once your app starts running, look for the following line in the Xcode console's logs:

`[Firebase/InAppMessaging][I-IAM180017] Starting InAppMessaging runtime with Firebase Installation ID YOUR_INSTALLATION_ID`